# How to change overflow:hidden to visible in lists without changing the height of the list

Tags: jquery, overflow

I'm trying to do an effect I've seen on some sites like alltop.com where there is a list and when you hover over a title (that has overflow set to hidden) you can see the entire title and the entire list doesn't move, as can be seen here:

http://screencast.com/t/fK5n4X3Fg

(Note: there is also another effect of showing the contents in a tooltip type effect, but I'm not interested in that - having already solved that problem).

Here is the what I've tried...here is the text:

```
  <div id="wprssmi_alltop_wrapper"><ul class="wprssmi_alltop_list"><li id="wrapper" ><h3    class="list_title"><a href="">BBC Sports Personality of the Year - live coverage</a></h3></li><li id="wrapper"><h3 ><a href="">Serious vulnerability reportedly leaves Samsung Galaxy S III and other devices wide open to malware</a></h3></li><li id="wrapper"><h3><a href="">Lanza’s body found with ammo for even more carnage</a></h3></li></ul></div>
```

and here is the jQuery

```
  jQuery('[id^=wrapper]').hover(function () {

    var cssObj = {
   'overflow': 'visible'
    }

   jQuery(this).css(cssObj);
  jQuery(this).next.hide();
 });
```

which essentially uses jQuery hover on a list item and tries to change the overflow to visible and take the next item and hide it like it works on alltop.com...unfortunatly I can't get this to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/amweiss/xFmsJ/9/

Does anybody know how you get this effect and how I might fix the code?

Thanks

Comment: _"and take the next item and hide it like it works on alltop.com"_ - On that site the next item isn't being hidden, it is being covered by the current item when the current item is expanded to display long titles over more than one line. By the way, you should use `<li class="wrapper">` and `$('.wrapper')`, rather than creating invalid html with duplicate ids with `$('[id^=wrapper]')` as a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

The effect on alltop.com is not done with jQuery - it's pure CSS. Here's your [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xFmsJ/27/).

All `<li>` have `position:relative` and `height` set to a height of one line of text (1.25em in their case).

All `<h3>` within `<li>` have `position:absolute` and `overflow:hidden`.

**On hover**, `<h3>` get `overflow:auto`, `height:auto` and a bigger `z-index` so they are rendered above the following list item. They also get a white background to cover the other item.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have seen the video and I know what are you trying to achieve, I don't think your approach is the best, but I can help you to fix your code.

Ok, first things first, the markup, you have 3 li elements who share the same id, a jQuery selector with an ID is only going to return the first element that matches, so is not going to  return all the li elements that you are after.

Just change you ids to classes an do a simple `jQuery('.wrapper')`

For the second thing, you are applying the overflow: visible on the li element when you need to do it on the h3.

```
jQuery('.wrapper').hover(function(){
  // here jQuery(this) is returning the li, you need to find the h3
  jQuery(this).find('h3').css(cssObj);
});
```

In your sample code, you forgot the () on the next function, that's why is not hiding the next li element.

```
jQuery(this).next().hide();
```

One last thing, when you are doing hover effects, you can setup two functions, one for the hover in and one for the hover out

```
jQuery('.wrapper').hover(function(){
  // This will execute on the hover in
  jQuery(this).find('h3').css('overflow', 'visible');
  jQuery(this).next().hide();
}, function(){
  // This will execute on the hover out
  // Restore everything to default
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi...thanks to all of you for helping me understand this...I'm going to try all suggestions (both for learning how this is done) but also use it in my WP plugin...thanks again.